# Can I use conditional statement to redirect user to certain view in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I wonder if it is possible to use a if condition to redirect user to a certain view in MVC4 C#?

for example

```
    public ActionResult MyController()
    {
        if(this) {
            return View1();
        }
        else {
            return View2();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke a named View like so:

```
public ActionResult MyController()
{
    if(true) 
    {
        return View("SomeViewA");
    }
    else {
        return View("SomeViewB");
    }

}
```

Comment: Does the "SomeViewA" and "B" correspond to what the file is named, or how can I give a view some certain name?

Comment: @starcorn: It's directly related to the name of the file (the View file). :)

Answer (score 1):

You can return a [`RedirectResult`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.redirectresult.aspx) to redirect to a specific URL.